# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager, Error self signed certificate getting chain

Tags: openssl, certificate, wso2, mdm, mobility

I'm trying to set up WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager. I'm following the instructions on the official documentation. I have a problem when generating certificates (step 4, c)
https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/iOS+Server+Configurations

When I execute the following cmd:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 730 -in ia.csr -CA ca_cert.pem -CAkey ca_private.pem -set_serial 044324343 -out ia.crt
```

I get this error:

```
Error self signed certificate getting chain.
```

how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of "Error self signed certificate getting chain." is that I use identical data for CA and IA certificate.

For further details refer http://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/12/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl/

Comment: I get the same error at the end that tutorial.  Somebody may have given a solution in the comments, but what worked for me was to enter two different sets of company information, between the two places where it was prompted for.

Comment: I also got the same issue. Seems there's an openssl version problem. On Mac I got this, then ran on ubuntu it worked without any issue.